# Why is Listboxes not displaying elements using Visual C++ 6?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

So, I have a Listbox problem where the entries I want it to show are not being displayed in Visual C++ 6.

The code is as follows.

```
switch (m) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: //To initiate the dialog box
    {
        HICON hicon = (HICON__ *)LoadImageW(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_ICONMAIN), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
        SendMessageW(h, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (long)hicon);
        RECT Rect;
        ::GetWindowRect(h, &Rect);
        ::SetWindowPos(h, HWND_TOPMOST, (::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2 - ((Rect.right - Rect.left)/2)), (::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2 - ((Rect.bottom - Rect.top)/2)), (Rect.right - Rect.left), (Rect.bottom - Rect.top), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        //Place items in listbox.
        const std::string StringArray[] = {"10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70"};
        SendMessage(h, LB_ADDSTRING, DROPDOWN1, (LPARAM)StringArray);
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: What's _c++ 6_ actually?

Comment: You are sending the message to the wrong window.  Use descriptive variables names, "h" sucks.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A quick google makes me think he means Visual C++ 6, but we can't be certain.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Well, I'm always playing possum for possums asking. I'm pretty sure there's an appropriate tag.

Comment: You need to send the strings one by one, you cannot send an array like that. Win32 knows nothing about std::string so you need to send the raw c-string i.e. StringArray[i].c_str()

Comment: yes iit is Microsoft Visual C++ 6 that ships with VS6.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you can use `LB_ADDSTRING` like that? `LB_ADDSTRING` requires a pointer to single zero-terminated string as `lparam`. You are sending a pointer to an *array*. And in addition to that the array contains `std::string` objects, which are not zero-terminated strings at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is not C#. Raw arrays are not classes and do not have methods.

Use `std::vector< std::string >`.

But before that, get [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1) and learn C++.

*ETA* Since you took out your edits where you were trying to call a non-existant `.Length` on the `StringArray` variable to traverse it in a for loop...

What in the MSDN documentation for the LB_ADDSTRING message makes you think it will accept a `std::string`? `std::string` is not a NULL terminated character array. Why would you think that you could cast an array of `std::string` to an `LPARAM`?

What you want is more like: *(I have not compiled this code.)*

```
typedef std::vector< std::string > string_vec;
const string_vec StringArray{"10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70"};

for( const auto & s : StringArray )
{
    SendMessage(h, LB_ADDSTRING, DROPDOWN1, (LPARAM)( s.c_str() ) );
}
```

[Range-based for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203382.aspx)

N.B. this is modern C++, not ancient, obsolete VC++ 6.